# RabbitMQ: Is it possible to have multiple channels associated with the same queue?

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I'm new to RabbitMQ. I understand that the channel is like an abstraction of a connection (being part of the real connection) and one channel is associated with one queue.

I know that multiple queues can utilize the same channel. But I'm wondering if multiple consumers can consume messages asynchronously from the same queue and if each consumer will have their own dedicated channel in that case.

To be for specific, I understand the following is possible:

```
                     / queue 1 - consumer 1 (via channel 1)
Producer -> Exchange - queue 2 - consumer 2 (via channel 2)
                     \ queue 3 - consumer 3 (via channel 3)
```

But what about the following?

```
                               / consumer 1 (via channel 1)
Producer -> Exchange - queue 1 - consumer 2 (via channel 2)
                               \ consumer 3 (via channel 3)
```

The reason I ask about this is I want to speed up my consumption via a channel pool (or multiple channels). However, I couldn't figure out a way to do that...

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple channels per connection.

```
Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
```

Do not share channel between threads.

When a channel is no longer needed, it should be closed.

```
channel.close()
```

If you are using spring:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "queue-name", concurrency = "4")
public void listener(Object requestObject) {
    // process
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please talk a little more about "thread"? According to [this](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-java.html) tutorial, by default, multi-threading is used when a consumer processes messages from a queue. In other words, inside `DeliverCallback`, it's already multithreading. So I am not quite sure what you mean by not sharing channel among threads